# Schedule a cron job for every saturday with the interval of 21 days

Tags: shell, unix, cron, sh

Please guide me how to schedule the cron job to run on every Saturday at 6am with the interval of 21 days.

Comment: Not making sense aside, that's not really how cron scheduling works.  Do you want every saturday, or do you want every 21 days?

Comment: I want to execute my script on every 21 days interval.

Comment: Assuming you want a saturday, but three weeks after the last run, why not specify the day-of-month as 21-27 and the day-of-week as 6? Just off the top of my head, you should check the edge cases.

Comment: @Karel Kubat: Sorry, but how the 'day-of-the-month' as 21-27 will work here ,suppose OP wants to schedule the job from 12th May 06:00 AM(Sat), then the dates would be completely different after 21 days.

Comment: Though i'm not sure, but this command should work in cron in an interval of 21 days after the last run on Saturday  : `00 06 */21 * 06 /path/script_name`

Comment: @User123, my 21-27 is just an example. To have the job roughly around the 12th, but on a Saturday, simply pick 10-16. In your May example that would fall on the 12th. I am working with the assumption that the exact day of the month is somewhat fluid, but that the Saturday requirement is strict. (Disclaimer, I don't fully understand the requirement.)

Answer (score 1):

How about you run the cron every Saturday, then you calculate if that is the 3rd Saturday and then you run your job?

```
* * * * 6 <condition> && <my Job>
```

The computation needs to be done for the condition as follows:

- Get the Week of the year `Wk=date +%V`
- `Wk % 3 == 0` can be used as the condition

So it Sums up to the cron entry as below:

```
* * * * 6 ((`date +%V` % 3 == 0)) && ls
```